# Is there Blazor WASM + WebAPI project template like there's `dotnet new react`?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I'd want to ask whether is there project template for webapi with web assembly blazor under one project

just like `dotnet new blazorserver` but with WASM instead of SignalR websocket

.NET Core 3.1

Comment: That's explained in the docs that show how to create each type of Blazor app, eg in the [Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) page, ie `dotnet new blazorwasm`. If you just run `dotnet new` you'll see all available templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted`

will create solution with `Client` and `Server` Folders

[image]

Comment: That's explained in the docs that show how to create each type of Blazor app, eg in the [Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) page

Answer (score -1):

I was never able to get the template working with the above answer. I logged a Github issue but the Blazor team couldn't answer why this wasn't working for me.

However, if you clone this repo, there is a sample Blazor Wasm app [here](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net/tree/master/RestClient.Net.Samples.Blazor). That should run and you will be able to get going straight away.